# Организация routes в node.js(Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Как правильно организовать маршрутизацию в приложении ? Структура (приблизительно):

```
-public
-views
-routes
-app.js
```

Не хочу писать в главном файле `app.get('/route', func())`, эта логика переносится в другие файлы. Которые будут, в данном случае, в папке `routes`.

Как сделать, чтобы, например, при переходе на `/index` рендерилась страница?
Пишу в `routes/index.js`:

```
exports.get = function(req, res) {
   res.render('index',{
       title: "Express",
       a: '<a href="#">Link</a>'
   });
};
```

A в `app.js`:

```
var router = require('routes');
app.get('/index', router.get);
app.get('/otherRoute', router.get);
```

Переход на `/otherRoute` провоцирует рендеринг того же `/index`, потому что не знаю, как правильно подключить\распределить\написать маршруты в `routes/`.
Не буду ведь подключать отдельно `var routesToOtherRoute = require('routes/otherRoute.js')` :)

- Как организовать маршрутизацию? Какие есть способы?
- Как вообще организовывать структуру? Посоветуйте статьи\уроки\книги\прочее по этой теме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите express.router. У вас должны быть разные файлы routes/index.js, routes/otherroute.js, и темплейты страничек index.jade и otherpage.jade тогда:

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);

var otherRoute = require('./routes/otherroute');
app.use('/otherroute', otherRoute);
```

./routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function () {
   router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('index',{
          title: "Express",
          a: '<a href="#">Link</a>'
      });
  })
    return router;
};
```

./routes/otherroute.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function () {
   router.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.render('otherpage',{
          title: "Express",
          a: '<a href="#">Link</a>'
      });
    })
    return router;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо поправил.